# Spotify update error message stops updates from occurring

Tags: updates, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

After todays update, I restarted my system and got this message:

[image]

When I check for updates it says that there are no updates available, and that last update was 7 days ago, which is not true since I updated today.

What should I do?

---

After running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` I can see the following error:

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1065838/

Fetched 173 kB in 11s (15.4 kB/s)

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease
```

Comment: what's the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ? use paste.ubuntu.com to add a link to your question.

Comment: @fossfreedom Heh, Spotify http://paste.ubuntu.com/1065838/ :)

Comment: This is a dupe of the link in your question - to be exact - `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59` will resolve this.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I don't understand why this things happen.

Comment: Not your fault - spotify had changed their authentication key.